# Create variable from MySQL datatable that can be used in HTML code

Tags: html, mysql, datatable

So I have a MySQL database and would like to create variables from that database that I can use in HTML code.
For example if I use `<video blablabla some stuff src="phpVariable" /video>`
I don't want to have a static URL in the HTML code. It should be assigned to a variable based on an SQL query. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to retrieve the data from the database that you wish to use, using a database query. From there, you can loop through all the results and output them.

Replace 'tablename' with the name of the database table and 'columnName' with the column name.

`$con` should be used to connect to your database. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   echo $row['columnName'];
}
```

If you only needed to retrieve one record, change the code to:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo $row['columnName'];
```

You can also store the retrieved data as a variable, like this:

```
$variableName = $row['columnName'];
// Then to use the variable in your code:
echo'<video src='.$variableName.'</video>';
```

This is very basic PHP though. Have you looked at some online guides?